# Proof involving set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show that $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=A$ then $B=\emptyset$

I know I have to use a proof by contradiction, so I should assume there exists a $b$ that is an element of $B$. But I am not sure where to go from there. Also, should this expression be equal to elements found in both $A$,$B$ and not just $A$.

Comment: If there is a $b$ in $B$ is it also in $A?$ if it is, is it in $(A\cup B) - (A\cap B)$?  What if it isn't?

Comment: when you say A u B do you mean $A \cup B$?

Comment: Yes. My apologies, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your equation as A = (A - B) $\cup$ (B - A).
Assume exists x in B.
Case x in A.  So either x in A - B or x in B - A.
Case x not in A,  So x in B - A.
In both cases, derive a contradiction.